# Stop Keypress when key has already been pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

My player presses <kbd>E</kbd> to open a chest and gets a point when done so. The problem is that they can press the key again and again.

How do I stop the player from interacting with the chest and getting infinite points? I don't want to just disable the object.

This is my code:

```
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject,CompareTag("Player") && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        anim.SetBool("opening", true);
        coins += 1;
        coinsText.text = "Coins: " + coins;
        
        Coin.SetActive(true);
        Destroy(textBox, .2f);
        getCoin  = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a bool to mark that the chest has already been opened like `isOpen` or `wasOpened`.

Then change your if statement to include a check that wasOpened is false. Set `wasOpened` to true inside your if block.

```
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && !wasOpened)
    {
        anim.SetBool("opening", true);
        coins += 1;
        coinsText.text = "Coins: " + coins;
        
        Coin.SetActive(true);
        Destroy(textBox, 0.2f);
        getCoin = true;
        wasOpened = true;
    }
}
```

This will mean you can only open it once. Remember to create the `wasOpened` variable further up with the rest of your variable declarations.

And as a note for future questions. Please provide code as text with code formatting like I have here. In order to answer your question I had to transcribe your code from an image which will put people off wanting to answer your questions.